# If the "transaction" for default.target fails, will systemd try to boot to emergency.target?

Tags: systemd

> If a unit A that conflicts with a unit B is scheduled to be started at the same time as B, the transaction will either fail (in case both are required part of the transaction) or be modified to be fixed (in case one or both jobs are not a required part of the transaction).
>
> -- [man systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

If we hit this failure case when systemd tries to reach `default.target` during boot, does systemd try to fall back to `emergency.target`?

Answer (score 0):

No.

It will fallback to `rescue.target` *[1]* instead, which is hardcoded in systemd *[2]*.
And, if that fails too, systemd will quit *[3][4]*.

Sources:

1. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/871fa294ff38b7fc0df7ddc2b03ec781d9f0cb8a/src/core/main.c#L2062
2. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/ad16158c10dfc3258831a9ff2f1a988214f51653/src/basic/special.h#L24
3. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/871fa294ff38b7fc0df7ddc2b03ec781d9f0cb8a/src/core/main.c#L2578
4. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/871fa294ff38b7fc0df7ddc2b03ec781d9f0cb8a/src/core/main.c#L2554

Comment: Thanks for finding the right function. I think the failure I mentioned will actually not fail `manager_load_startable_unit_or_warn()`, it will fail at `manager_add_job()`, so there is no fallback and `systemd` will just quit.